# zooming and dragging images using matrix in android

Tags: android, image, drag-and-drop, zooming

i got the following code (from Hello android by Ed Burnette) working nicely and i am able to drag and zoom for an image.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Touch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
   private static final String TAG = "Touch";
   // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

   // We can be in one of these 3 states
   static final int NONE = 0;
   static final int DRAG = 1;
   static final int ZOOM = 2;
   int mode = NONE;

   // Remember some things for zooming
   PointF start = new PointF();
   PointF mid = new PointF();
   float oldDist = 1f;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      view.setOnTouchListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

      // Dump touch event to log
      dumpEvent(event);

      // Handle touch events here...
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
         start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
         mode = DRAG;
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
         oldDist = spacing(event);
         Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
         if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
         }
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
         mode = NONE;
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         if (mode == DRAG) {
            // ...
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                  event.getY() - start.y);
         }
         else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
               matrix.set(savedMatrix);
               float scale = newDist / oldDist;
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
         }
         break;
      }

      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      return true; // indicate event was handled
   }

   /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
   private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
            "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int action = event.getAction();
      int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
      sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
      if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
         sb.append("(pid ").append(
               action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
         sb.append(")");
      }
      sb.append("[");
      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
         sb.append("#").append(i);
         sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
         sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
         sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
         if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
      }
      sb.append("]");
      Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
   }

   /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
   private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
      return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
   }

   /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
   private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
      point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
   }
}
```

however, can some1 kindly explain clearly the functions of the following 5 lines within the above code?

```
savedMatrix.set(matrix);
matrix.set(savedMatrix);
matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,event.getY() - start.y);
float scale = newDist / oldDist;
matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
```

thanks in advance for the explanation :)

Comment: You might need to add 'imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);' to use this code.

Comment: Where can I find the full code?

Comment: This code seems to work fine, I mean I can see all Logcat messages about move, drag, etc, but my ImageView doesn't move on the screen, nor zoom, wired thing, what may the issue be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
savedMatrix.set(matrix);
```

copying "matrix" content into "savedMatrix"

```
matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,event.getY() - start.y);
```

"matrix" determines some transformation, like zoom and move. "postTranslate" adds "move" transformation to transformation already defined in "matrix". I.e. "matrix" contains some zoom transformation, and then after applying postTranslate it will determine "zoom and then move" transformation.

```
float scale = newDist / oldDist;
matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
```

Adding zoom transformation with center in (mid.x, mid.y) to transformation already defined in "matrix"

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative solution, I used an example from Android's dev blog. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

The main reason I used this example instead of the one you implemented is that they wrote an modified version of the blog article. This article presents how to handle multitouch events on devices which don't have Android 2.2 or above installed.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html