# How to implement iPhone like 'move and scale' functionality for image in Android?

Tags: android, image

I have an image editing application in android. I want to **move and scale selected part of an image** like this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496767/iphonehow-to-implement-move-and-scale-functionality-for-image-fetched-from-ph) .I am used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881778/zooming-and-dragging-images-using-matrix-in-android).But it does not work for me. I do not  want to move and scale the imageview and the entire image,only part of the image.ie, I want to scale and move the part of the image with in the white box.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

For implementing pinch-to-zoom and moving feature read [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html).

If you want have some "constant" part you can just create drawable with 100% alfa in the center and 50% alfa at edges (+white line if you want), and connect your "constant" image with "resizable" image in one `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: What is meant by '100% alfa in the center and 50% alfa at edges'?Could you please show me an example.I have little knowledge with images.

Comment: Just read this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch There is an example of button, but you ned reverse variant - transparent center and non-transparent edges